# MULE 4 - is there a way to check if an XML file contains just one document?

Tags: xml, mule, mule4

I have an input XML file (person.xml), to make it simple:

```
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Doe></surname>
</person>
```

Is there a way to check if the file `person.xml` contains one and only one entry, just the one above?

An example of a **WRONG** file:

```
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Doe></surname>
</person>
<person>
    <name>Jane</name>
    <surname>Walker</surname>
</person>
```

A proper document should have only one person in it.

Can I achieve this without using Java?

Comment: `<surname>` was incorrectly closed in the examples. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of DataWeave 2.0 to [read](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-readurl) the file and using sizeOf determine what you need.

For e.g.

**Input**

```
<persons>
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
</person>
<person>
    <name>John1</name>
    <surname>Doe2</surname>
</person>
</persons>
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
a: if(sizeOf(payload.persons) >1) "invalid" else "valid"
```

**Output**

```
{
  "a": "invalid"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing such as an XML document with multiple entries. A valid XML document has a single root element. The wrong example has 2, hence is not a valid document. Any correct XML parsers will reject the input as invalid.

Mule Transform component will throw a MULE:EXPRESSION error, but it is not a good idea to assume this is caused by having multiple root. An expression error can have many different causes. I strongly recommend to not try to parse the error description. It is not guaranteed that descriptions remain unchanged and it is a bad practice.

I would just [handle](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/error-handling) the MULE:EXPRESSION as a generic error. You can return the description if you want to clarify the cause.

Example:

```
Message               : "Illegal to have multiple roots (start tag in epilog?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,2], while reading `payload` as Xml.
 [row,col]: [5,2]" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
...
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
```